# Word,PDF Upload and download using Rails 3.1.x on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, download

Hi I am looking for a very good solution to upload and download document file types directly to and from  the database using rails 3.1.x ... I used paperclip for that but image-magick is pain to install on windows..please help me in these... Thanks

Comment: Do you plan to deploy your app on Windows?

Comment: yes will it be a problem to deploy on windows?

Comment: Refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890226/should-i-give-up-on-deploying-rails-under-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you're not uploading images, you don't need to install image-magick.

As for storing to the database using Paperclip, [see this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596725/store-image-in-database-using-rails-paperclip-plugin).